# HTML image not found django

Tags: python, django

I know that there are a lot of questions with this error but I am trying all of the tips and I am not having success yet.

I installed django and I want to introduce two images in my web map. I try everything and the images are not found yet.

I have a folder static inside my project and inside static I have a folder images with the images. I also tested with the folder images outside the static folder.

In my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gic\static')]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'images')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
```

and in index.html file

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "coalmine_logo.png" %}" alt="Cinque Terre" width=350 height=120/>
```

and an error appears:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/static/coalmine_logo.png 404 (Not Found)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to add at the end of your url.py `urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()`, and on top of that file `from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns` I am not certain that will solve the issue, but worth a try.

Comment: Also, since you are using static root, it might be worth trying to use `python3 manage.py collectstatic`, I don't think it should be the issue (since for me that was only needed when I pushed my code to live), but it *could* be something that might help.

Comment: If your image is in /static/images/coalmine_logo.png then you need to `{% static "images/coalmine_logo.png" %}`

Comment: I add the urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() and from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns in url.py. Also I try python manage.py collectstatic and thsi was the result: "0 static files copied to 'D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic\static', 170 unmodified."  In index.html I also changed to {% static "images/coalmine_logo.png" %}. Nothing happens.

Comment: It's because you're working for a coal mine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you images are within a subfolder of your static folder you need to add that folder name to the path. In your template it should look like this:

```
{% static 'images/coalmine_logo.png' %}
```

Edit:
The reason this wasn't working for the poster was because they had their static files they were trying to access in the directory that was specified in `STATIC_ROOT` in their settings file. In development django does not look in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory for statics files, it looks in the directories listed in the `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable. This was fixed for the poster by moving their files into the directory that matched their line `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'gic\static')`

Comment: Yes, I have in that way. See updating in main question.

Comment: Are you sure you are spelling the file name correctly then? With what you said you have done in the comments above, if the file is spelled correctly then it should be found.

Comment: Yes. I even try with other figure (in jpg format). I copy the name of the image, so there is not mistakes and still it is not found. I do not know what to do anymore.

Comment: What is the name of the folder that has your project and the manage.py file it in?

Comment: The manage.py is inside D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic. However my static folder is in D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic\gic\static. It is confused because I follow an online course and I think I originated the folders in a wrong way.

Comment: In your settings.py file, can you add in a line `print(BASE_DIR)` and tell me what that prints out?

Comment: The return was this: D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic

Comment: Can you copy the full file path of the image you are trying to load in? I'm really trying to find some way I can help, but everything that you have done seems like it should be correct.

Comment: My image is in this full directory D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic\static\images\coalmine_logo.png

Comment: If you typed that path right then that means your images directory is already in the path that you specified as `STATIC_ROOT` in your settings file. I don't think that django will look for static files there when you are in development mode. You said earlier that you have another directory named static in another folder at `D:\Cursos\Webmapping\gic\gic\gic\static`. Try moving your images folder into there, because I believe that is where django is actually going to be looking for the static files when you in development, assuming you haven't made changes to your `STATICFILES_DIRS` variable yet

Comment: Yes!!! I get it. Thank you Nathan Roberts.

Comment: That worked then?

Comment: Yes!! I did what you said and it works. If you want edit your answer and I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: I added it to my answer.